# Simulating rounds of coin flipping that stops when it gets a significant result, and plotting the probability of a significant result

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics

I have a question on a problem sheet that I'm not sure how to answer:

"An experimenter is flipping a fair coin (p=0.5) in a multistage experiment with rounds of 10 coin flips (stopping if the results are significant after each round) until a maximum goal of 100 coin flips.

"You are attempting to get the Type 1 error rate for this multistage procedure.

"Simulate the results of this experiment, and plot the probability of getting a significant result after each stage."

I'm guessing that I have to use a for loop, but I'm not sure quite where to start, or how to plot the probability of getting a significant result after each stage *which I'm taking to mean each N=10 round of coin flipping).

Comment: I realise it's tricky getting started when you don't know where to start, but you haven't shown what you've tried so far. I recommend you review this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask particularly the part regarding "Search and research". The reasons for this are outlined in this link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions However, to get you started, and this might not be the best way to solve your question, but  look up "nested for loops" and "adding a counter to a loop".

Comment: @LeroyTyrone , Thank you very much! I'm not always sure how to ask good questions, so this is helpful!